# list comprehension and transforming data

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've been trying to convert some of my functions where I use a for loop by using list comprehension. Here is my first version of the function,

```
def adstocked_advertising(data, adstock_rate):
    '''
    Transforming data with applying Adstock transformations
    data - > The dataframe that is being used to create Adstock variables
    adstock_rate -> The rate at of the adstock

    ex. data['Channel_Adstock'] = adstocked_advertising(data['Channel'], 0.5)
    '''
    adstocked_advertising = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i == 0: 
            adstocked_advertising.append(data[i])
        else:
            adstocked_advertising.append(data[i] + adstock_rate * adstocked_advertising[i-1])            
    return adstocked_advertising
```

I want to convert it to this,

```
def adstocked_advertising_list(data, adstock_rate):
    adstocked_advertising = [data[i] if i == 0 else data[i] + adstock_rate * data[i-1] for i in range(len(data))]

    return adstocked_advertising
```

However, when viewing the df after running both functions I get two different values.

```
data['TV_adstock'] = adstocked_advertising_list(data['TV'], 0.5)
data['TV_adstock_2'] = adstocked_advertising(data['TV'], 0.5)
```

here is output,

```
data.head()
```

[image]

```
data.tail()
```

[image]

I am not too sure why the first two rows are the same and then from there the numbers are all different. I am new to list comprehension so I may be missing something here.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to convert it to a list comprehension? Sometimes the loop is more legible. I am not aware of significant computational advantages to list comprehension, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/8793975

Comment: In the function version `adstocked_advertising_list()`, you reference `i` but i is not defined as a parameter, it's just dangling, presumably a dangling non-zero final value from the for-loop version, hence in your function the `data[i] if i == 0` clause is never used. So just fix that and it should work.

Comment: @enumaris , the main reason for this is to learn how to use list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the previously generated element in the list, and list comprehensions are not well suited to this type of problem. They work well for operations that only need to look at a single element at once. 
 [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794774/python-list-comprehension-access-last-created-element) goes into more detail.

In your initial example, you use `adstock_rate * adstocked_advertising[i-1]`.  The list comprehension version uses `adstock_rate * data[i-1]`, which is why you are getting different results.

A standard for loop works just fine for your use case.  You could switch to using enumerate, as `for i in range(len(data))` is discouraged.

```
if data:
    res = [data[0]]
for index, item in enumerate(data[1:]):
        results.append(item + rate * data[index-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess there are specific use cases where list compression is used over a standard for loop and vise versa.

Comment: `if index == 0` will only be true once, at the beginning of the loop. Append the first element, and then iterate unconditionally.

Comment: Your translation of the algorithm is now incorrect because the first element will be appended twice.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed your logic in the list comp version. Originally, your `else` formula looked like:

```
data[i] + adstock_rate * adstocked_advertising[i-1]
```

But the list comprehension version looks like:

```
data[i] + adstock_rate * data[i-1]
```

The first version accesses the `i-1`th element of the *result* list, while the second version accesses the `i-1`th element of the *input* list.

`index == 0` is only true once at the beginning of the list. Why not eliminate the conditional:

```
def adstocked_advertising(data, adstock_rate):
    if data:
        res = [data[0]]

        for i in range(1, len(data)):
            res.append(data[i] + adstock_rate * res[i-1])

        return res
```