# Bubble Sort using Slice and __setitem__ Methods

Tags: python, sorting, slice

Based on [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57358986/6553328), I've tried to run the following bubble sort algorithm, which uses `slice` and `__setitem__` methods; I'm positive that there'd be something simple that I'm not doing right, not sure what that might be?

#### Code

```
def bubblesort(l):
    [l.__setitem__(slice(i, i + 2), (l[i:i + 2] if l[i] < l[i + 1] else l[i +  1:i - 1:-1])) for j in range(0, len(l)) for i in range(0, len(l) - 1)]
    return l

l = [1,5,-5,0,10,100]
bubblesort(l)
print(l)
```

#### Desired Output

```
[-5, 0, 1, 5, 10, 100]
```

Comment: Do not use list-comprehensions for side-effects. That is not Pythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i == 0`, `l[i +  1:i - 1:-1]` evaluates to `[]` so you end up shortening your list mid iteration.

Comment: It could be replaced with `[l[i+1], l[i]]` to achieve the same effect without the accidental index wraparound; you only needed two elements after all. Alternatively, you could use `l[i:i+2][::-1]`, which has symmetry with the other use (you just add the canonical reversing slice after, `[::-1]`).