# How to access the previous item calculated in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I create a list, I use the one-liner

```py
new_list = [func(item) for item in somelist]
```

Is there a simple way to write the following *iteration* in one line?

```py
new_list = [0]
for _ in range(N):
    new_list.append(func(new_list[-1]))
```

or even

```py
new_list = [0]
for t in range(N):
    new_list.append(func(t, new_list[-1]))
```

i.e. each item is calculated based on the previous item with a specific initializer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list comprehension - access last created element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794774/python-list-comprehension-access-last-created-element)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) to store the returning value of the last call to `func`, but since you also want the initial value `0` to be in the list, you would have to join it separately:

```
new_list = [i := 0] + [i := func(i) for _ in range(N)]
```

or even:

```
new_list = [i := 0] + [i := func(t, i) for t in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) exists exactly for that:

```
from itertools import accumulate

new_list = list(accumulate(range(N), func))  # == [0, func(0, 1), func(func(0, 1), 2), ...]
```

If you wish to dump the `N`, just use `accumulate` like so:

```
from itertools import accumulate

new_list = list(accumulate(range(N), lambda x, y: func(x)))  # == [0, func(0), func(fnc(0)), ...]
```

Comment: This does the latter of the two requested lists, not the former though.

Comment: @blhsing not too hard to remove an argument.